# Query Export with Google Apps Script setting compression

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I can't get compression working when exporting a large (16GB) Biq Query table to GCS using appscript. I set compression type to GZIP and destination format to NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON but it does not compress the file, just outputs 116 files instead?

I've tried `extract.compression =` and `extract.setcompression =` but it doesn't make any difference. How can I resolve this?

```
function extractBigQueryToCloudStorage(compressionType,csFileUri, datasetId, tableId,projectId) { 

  //
  var compressionType='GZIP';
  var csFileUri='gs://xxxxxxxxxx/bq_extracts/xxxxxxxxxx.*.JSON';
  var datasetId='xxxxxxxxxx';
  var tableId='xxxxxxxxxx';
  var projectId='xxxxxxxxxx';
  var bqTable = checkBigQueryTable(projectId, datasetId, tableId);

  var fnStart = new Date();

    try {
        var tableReference = BigQuery.newTableReference();
        tableReference.setProjectId(projectId);
        tableReference.setDatasetId(datasetId);
        tableReference.setTableId(tableId);

        var extract = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationExtract()
        extract.setDestinationFormat('NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON');
        extract.compression=(compressionType);
        extract.setDestinationUris([csFileUri]);
        extract.setSourceTable(tableReference);

        var configuration = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
        configuration.setExtract(extract);
        var newJob = BigQuery.newJob();
        newJob.setConfiguration(configuration);

        var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(newJob, projectId);
        var jobId = job.getJobReference().getJobId();    
        var status = job.getStatus();

        while (status.getState() != 'DONE'){
            Logger.log(status.getState());
            if(status.getState() == 'PENDING'){
                Utilities.sleep(100);
            }      
            if (status.getErrorResult() == true){     
                Logger.log('BigQuery file upload error: %s', status.getErrors());
            }       
            status = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId, jobId).getStatus();
        }  
    } catch(err) { 
        Logger.log('BigQuery file upload error: %s', err);  
        return err;   
    } 
    var fnEnd = new Date();
    Logger.log(status.getState());
    Logger.log('Function loadCloudStorageFileToBigQuery elapsed time: %sms', fnEnd - fnStart);
    Logger.log(status.errorResult);   // check for notification of extract too big (e.g. > 1 Gb)
    return status.getState();


    // Function to determine if a BigQuery table exists. Returns boolean
function checkBigQueryTable(projectId, datasetId, tableId) {  
    try { 
        var job = BigQuery.Tables.get(projectId, datasetId, tableId);
        return true;
    } catch(err) { 
        Logger.log('Table %s does not exist' , tableId);    
        return false;   
    } 

}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did seems correct to me. Are you sure the produced output is not GZIP? Even with compression set to GZIP, BigQuery would still output 116 files in GZIP format, one per shard (with ".JSON" as the extension as indicated in your output URI).

I tried with the following code using setCompression and it works for me:

```
var tableReference = BigQuery.newTableReference();
tableReference.setProjectId(projectId);
tableReference.setDatasetId(datasetId);
tableReference.setTableId(tableId);

var extract = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationExtract()
extract.setDestinationFormat('NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON');
extract.setCompression('GZIP');
extract.setDestinationUris(['gs://xxxxx/output.*.JSON']);
extract.setSourceTable(tableReference);

var configuration = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
configuration.setExtract(extract);
var newJob = BigQuery.newJob();
newJob.setConfiguration(configuration);

var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(newJob, projectId);
Logger.log("JobId is " + projectId + ":" + jobId);
```

You can check whether your setCompression takes effect or not by using the [bq command-line client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool):

```
bq --format=prettyjson show -j <datasetId>:<jobId>
```

When it works, you should see these lines:

```
...
"extract": {
  "compression": "GZIP", 
  "destinationFormat": "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON", 
...
```